# SMS BroadcastReceiver stops working after sometime

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have an app which does some task once it receives a SMS. I have implemented it using BroadcastReceiver. After installing the app, it works fine for sometime.

Afterwards, I notice that onReceive event of BroadcastReceiver is not triggered. To troubleshoot, I restarted my app service and connected the mobile to Android Studio Logcat. As earlier, initially it detected new SMS and everything worked fine. When I sent SMS after 30 mins, onReceive event was not triggered. There was no messages related to my app during that 30 mins in Logcat.

Looks like BroadcastReceiver service is killed. What could be the reason. How can I troubleshoot? I am testing this app in Android 8.1.

My code below

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chickoo.whereareyou" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.chickoo.whereareyou.IncomingSms"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".LocationUpdatesService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Broadcast receiver class file

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {



    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "SMS Recd1");
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
            Log.i("SmsReceiver", "SMS Recd2");

            if (bundle != null) {
                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "SMS Recd3");

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "SMS Recd5");

                    String senderNum = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                    if (message.equals("WAY")) {
                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "GPSlocn service to be stared");
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, LocationUpdatesService.class);
                            intent1.putExtra("SENDNUM", senderNum);

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                context.startForegroundService(intent1);
                            } else {
                                context.startService(intent1);
                            }


                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "GPSlocn service started");

                    }
                } 
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Unless you have a persistent foreground service which displays a notification this is normal. See [https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services).

Comment: I am using SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION and I thought this is exempted as per https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: Yes, @MikeM.I have registered the class in manifest

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the the EMUI, MIUI etc were killing the background tasks. After whitelisting the app, it works fine now.

Comment: And how to whitelist?

Comment: Hi @Karthik,  even using whitelist(if you mean allow background running and exclude for battery optimizing), the app will still be killed after a long time. How did you resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After whitelisting I don't face any issues @gg

Comment: @Karthik Good to know. How did you do whitelist in EMUI? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for whitelisting just go [miui phones] apps >> Manage apps >>[select app for whitelisting] >> battery saver >> select "no restriction".