# SMS receiver stops working after sometime

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, whitelist, event-bus

I have a requirement of reading incoming SMS from a few of the e-commerce apps. For that, I added BroadcastReceiver for receiving SMS and reading that. Also added runtime permission of **READ_SMS** for that, done setting a *priority* of 1000 for that receiver. I tested it for a few days sending a few dummy messages, along with the eCommerce app messages similar to -

> Delivered: Your package with Macbook Air
> ... has been successfully delivered. More info
> at http://amzn.in/bAieP6f

> Your SnapDeal order AWB:12791911327207 is delivered on 19-02-2020 at
> 16:20 by Xpressbees received by Username. You may contact us on
> 020-49116100.

> Delivered: Gillette Sensitive Ski... from flipkart.com was delivered.
> Click here to give feedback: http://fkrt.it/u33XFQHHHH

And so on.

But after testing for a few days, around 3-4 days, the app ***suddenly stopped working*** to read those and any other messages.

**Note**: The device I am using is - MI A1, with the Android 9 (Pie) version.

The code for the same, I used is as follows -

1. **SmsListener.java (Broadcast Receiver class)**

   ```
   public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("TAG","msg receiver entered");


            if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String messageBody = "";
                String msg_from = "";
                for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {

                    msg_from = smsMessage.getServiceCenterAddress();
                        Log.d("TAG","msg_from = "+msg_from);
                        Log.d("TAG","msgBody = "+messageBody);


                }
            }
        }
   ```

   }
2. **AndroidManifest.xml**

a) necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

b) receiver entry

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.SmsListener"
        >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

I also tried to modify the priority to 999, as suggested in a few other StackOverflow answers to a similar query, but no luck.

Though, the same code is still working in the demo app, but unluckily not in my app.

I also tried using EventBus referring [here](https://github.com/tegalan/android-sms-receiver). That too worked for some time, unless I again tried testing using

> Your SnapDeal order AWB:12791911327207 is delivered on 19-02-2020 at
> 16:20 by Xpressbees received by Username. You may contact us on
> 020-49116100.

Don't know what's wrong, as the code looks fine, and was working fine in the same app, also the same code working fine in another demo app.

I also found a suggestion to whitelist the App in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679143/1479511). Though, don't know how to do that or whether its the perfect solution.

Please suggest how to achieve reading incoming SMS, or what I am missing or going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Is better to do it with Service with START_STICKY flag. Android can kill any background app at any time.

Comment: @JKLIR tried using Service too, but still not working :(

Comment: @MikeM. Not sure, if thats the reason, as its stock Android.

Comment: @MikeM I tried searching for those settings mentioned in most of your suggested links, but unable to find any of them (MIUI optimization / autostart / permissions). So, looks like its not like the other Xiaomi devices.

Comment: @MikeM but if its really the Xiaomi issue, then why its working in the demo app in the same Xiaomi device?

Comment: Is that what you meant? I didn't understand what you were saying in that part in your question. Well, that would indicate an issue with your specific app, but there's not really enough information here to be able to determine what that is. What you've shown here is basically just the minimal setup needed, which any generic example would have.

Comment: Just like what I mentioned, I have added a specific code in my app to read the received SMS, which worked for sometime, and stopped working after a few days. Then I checked the same in the other demo app, where its still working.

Comment: @MikeM and afterwards, I added EventBus in my app, for the same purpose, by which getting SMS receive event started working, but that too for a very short time

Comment: All you're doing in your Receiver is logging the service center number, and the body? How have you determined that it's not working, exactly?

Comment: I determined by the onReceive event not being fired at all

Comment: Not sure, and even hard to believe, but is it possible due to those specific messages of eCommerce apps?

Comment: OK, how are you determining that, exactly? Are you just going by the presence/absence of those logs? Also, are you certain that the missed messages are actually SMS, not MMS maybe, or possibly RCS?

Comment: yes, along with those logs, I debugged as well. Missed messages are SMS only, as I am only sending them to test that onReceive()

Comment: Dunno. At this point, if all you're doing is logging, I don't really have anything else to suggest, apart from trying to do something more noticeable than just logs there; e.g., a `Notification`, even a `Toast`, etc. I'm not sure what you did to debug, but many similar issues I've come across here have just been due to the user missing the logs, for whatever reason.

Comment: Also tried notifications, but first it has to come inside the onReceive event before triggering notifications, and that is not happening :(

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm still not sure how you're determining that it's not, exactly. You might start digging through all of the logs you get, looking for any from the system indicating a failed broadcast, a stopped Receiver or app, etc.

Comment: It shouldn't be too tough to identify whether a method is getting called or not :) I will keep trying to identify the reason, as per your suggestion :)

Comment: You'd think so, but somehow users consistently surprise me in what they think should be happening, and what actually happens. For example, [this recent SMS question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62511917) where the user thought `sendTextMessage()` wasn't working at all, but it was, in fact, working the whole time, because they were looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: Okay, but not the same case here :/ 
It seems the Oreo and higher versions issue, as the same thing is working on Android 7 (Nougat) version. Though, not very sure about it, as even worked in Pie, initially, but later stopped working

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean that it was the same exact issue; just that users often aren't familiar enough with the mechanics to know what to look for, or to properly interpret what they're observing.

Comment: Btw, this site might be of some interest for you: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi. I'm not sure that it has any more information than the posts I linked previously, but it might be worth a read.

Comment: MI A1 (the one in which, I am facing issue, right now) is Android One device by Xiaomi.

Comment: @MikeM Thanks buddy, I have made it working :) Was just missing a thing

Comment: Well, don't keep it a secret. :-) What was it?

Comment: Hahaha...please check the posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, made it working in higher versions too, just by adding

```
android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
```

in the receiver tag in AndroidManifest.xml

and made it something like -

```
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.SmsListener"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
            >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

Comment: This should be somewhat concerning, actually. That `permission` attribute basically ensures that only the system can broadcast to your Receiver. The fact that it stops working without that guarding permission leads me to believe that you have some possibly-malicious app on your device that is sending broadcasts to it for some reason, and crashing your app there, as the delivered `Intent` will not be what you're expecting. If I were you, I would temporarily remove that again, and try to investigate.

Comment: Even its working now, after removal of that permission. :O

Comment: Not sure, if I should actually rely on that permission or not.

Comment: You do absolutely want that `permission` there, ultimately, but not having it won't prevent the system from sending valid broadcasts. It would just allow other apps to to broadcast to your Receiver, too. If you do want to investigate that, and it was taking a couple of days for your app to stop working, you would need let it go until then to see what's happening. Probably the simplest test would be to wrap everything inside `onReceive()` with a `try`-`catch`, and log any Exceptions, as well. Anyhoo, it was just a suggestion. It's obviously up to you if want to spend the time to do it.

Comment: Having the `permission` prevents the bad broadcasts from getting to your Receiver, so you're good there, but that bad app would still be around, if that is indeed the issue.